# I logged in and my account history is gone.

Tags: support, user-accounts

Help. I logged in and my account history has disappeared. Do I now have two accounts?

Comment: Something may have, indeed, gone wrong. I found two accounts that may be yours: [steven gregory](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/75410/steven-gregory) and [Steven Gregory](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/219577/steven-gregory). The upper case one has nearly 10k rep, so it's likely your main account. Read [this help center page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and follow the instructions.

Comment: Because the new account is mostly unused, you may also consider [this procedure](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/reset-password). I'm afraid I don't know much about the details, because the SE staff handles such things.